# Load and read elements from this XML in PHP

Tags: php, xml

http://pastebin.com/hXuHpcUQ

Is what I have..

How can I load and read the data?

so for each node, I could do something like:

```
foreach($nodes as $node)
{
    echo $node->getElementsByTagName("url") . "<br />";
}
```

But how should $nodes be defined to grab alle the `<node type="link">`'s?

This is what I have started out and currently got:

```
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    try
    {
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->loadXml(file_get_contents('new.xml'));
    }catch(Exception $e)
    {
        continue;
    }
```

I would like to output the value in `<url>` inside each `<node></node>` element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use SimpleXML - should be something like.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('new.xml');
foreach ($xml->node as $node) {
  echo $node->url;
}
```

(untested..)

Comment: I wrapped it around foreach($xml->body as $b) { foreach($b->node as $node) {} } and it worked :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should read about [DOMXPath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)

Your query will look like (not tested):

```
$nodes = $xpath_obj->query("//node[type='link']/url");
```